# can‘t ping the ip addr after send a wget request

Tags: networking, wget, ping, router

I am facing a problem while try to visit a remote website address.

Please help me out.

first.everything is ok.

second.send a wget request.and recive "Connection reset by peer"

then.ping not working.

and i found the command "ip route get xxx" output has changed after send wget.

and "ip route flush cache" can fixed ping.but wget still not working.

```
CoreELEC:~ # ip route get 104.26.12.50
104.26.12.50 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.179 

CoreELEC:~ # ping 104.26.12.50
PING 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.26.12.50: seq=0 ttl=53 time=179.858 ms
64 bytes from 104.26.12.50: seq=1 ttl=53 time=180.024 ms
64 bytes from 104.26.12.50: seq=2 ttl=53 time=179.980 ms
^Z[1]+  Stopped                    ping 104.26.12.50

CoreELEC:~ # wget https://104.26.12.50/
Connecting to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50:443)
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

CoreELEC:~ # ip route get 104.26.12.50
104.26.12.50 via 104.26.12.50 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.179 

CoreELEC:~ # ping 104.26.12.50
PING 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50): 56 data bytes
^Z[2]+  Stopped                    ping 104.26.12.50

CoreELEC:~ # ip route flush cache

CoreELEC:~ # ip route get 104.26.12.50
104.26.12.50 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.179 

CoreELEC:~ # ping 104.26.12.50
PING 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.26.12.50: seq=0 ttl=53 time=179.730 ms
64 bytes from 104.26.12.50: seq=1 ttl=53 time=179.616 ms
^Z[3]+  Stopped                    ping 104.26.12.50
```

traceroute result

```
CoreELEC:~ # ip route flush cache

CoreELEC:~ # traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.770 ms  0.752 ms  0.650 ms
 2  10.11.128.1 (10.11.128.1)  3.400 ms  3.728 ms  3.249 ms
 3  211.136.62.237 (211.136.62.237)  5.067 ms  4.482 ms  4.310 ms
 4  111.24.14.45 (111.24.14.45)  4.594 ms  4.720 ms  4.791 ms
 5  111.24.2.110 (111.24.2.110)  16.499 ms^Z[1]+  Stopped                    traceroute 104.26.12.50

CoreELEC:~ # wget https://104.26.12.50/
Connecting to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50:443)
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

CoreELEC:~ # traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.179 (192.168.1.179)  1675.641 ms !H  2751.899 ms !H  3000.313 ms !H
CoreELEC:~ # traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.179 (192.168.1.179)  724.558 ms !H  2989.973 ms !H  3000.084 ms !H

CoreELEC:~ # ip route flush cache

CoreELEC:~ # traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.831 ms  0.907 ms  0.807 ms
 2  10.11.128.1 (10.11.128.1)  10.854 ms  7.432 ms  2.965 ms
 3  211.136.62.237 (211.136.62.237)  24.308 ms  7.107 ms  19.634 ms
 4  111.24.14.45 (111.24.14.45)  4.821 ms  4.816 ms  4.593 ms
 5^Z[2]+  Stopped                    traceroute 104.26.12.50
```

another mac at same local network：

```
bash-3.2$ traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.779 ms  0.954 ms  0.986 ms
 2  10.11.128.1 (10.11.128.1)  3.959 ms  3.594 ms  3.680 ms
 3  211.136.62.237 (211.136.62.237)  5.088 ms  5.719 ms  4.760 ms
 4  111.24.14.45 (111.24.14.45)  5.277 ms  4.875 ms  5.072 ms
 5  111.24.2.106 (111.24.2.106)  7.508 ms
    111.24.2.110 (111.24.2.110)  5.291 ms
    111.24.17.157 (111.24.17.157)  5.907 ms
 6  221.176.21.150 (221.176.21.150)  38.841 ms  7.606 ms  9.093 ms
^C

bash-3.2$ wget https://104.26.12.50/
Connecting to 104.26.12.50:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.

bash-3.2$ traceroute 104.26.12.50
traceroute to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.674 ms  1.162 ms  1.141 ms
 2  10.11.128.1 (10.11.128.1)  4.327 ms  4.152 ms  4.043 ms
 3  211.136.62.237 (211.136.62.237)  5.764 ms  18.867 ms  19.749 ms
 4  111.24.14.45 (111.24.14.45)  7.277 ms  5.256 ms  5.969 ms
^C
```

i am use coreelec9.0.0(Linux3.14.29),the 'ip' command in BusyBox is unsupport full options.

```
CoreELEC:~ # cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.14.29 (adamg@zulu) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180425 [linaro-7.3-2018.05 revision d29120a424ecfbc167ef90065c0eeb7f91977701] (Linaro GCC 7.3-2018.05) ) #1 SMP Sat Feb 16 12:49:23 GMT 2019

CoreELEC:~ # uname -a
Linux CoreELEC 3.14.29 #1 SMP Sat Feb 16 12:49:23 GMT 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux

CoreELEC:~ # lsb_release -a
CoreELEC (official): 9.0.0


CoreELEC:~ # ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 4096 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:7c:02:e9:85:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:7c:02:e9:85:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

CoreELEC:~ # ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 4096 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:7c:02:e9:85:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.179/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fe7c:2ff:fee9:85c5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:7c:02:e9:85:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

CoreELEC:~ # ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.1.179 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 scope link 

CoreELEC:~ # ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

tracepath output

```
CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin # tracepath -4 104.26.12.50
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.169ms 
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.090ms 
 2:  192.168.1.1                                           1.064ms pmtu 1492
 2:  10.11.128.1                                           4.250ms 
 3:  211.136.62.237                                       31.305ms 
 4:  111.24.14.45                                          6.265ms 
 5:  111.24.17.157                                         6.674ms asymm  6 
 6:  221.176.21.150                                        7.991ms asymm  8 
 7:  221.183.25.202                                        7.046ms asymm  9 
 8:  221.183.55.113                                        9.257ms 
 9:  223.120.22.18                                         8.574ms asymm  8 
10:  223.120.6.54                                        180.044ms asymm 11 
11:  223.120.6.54                                        181.604ms 
^Z[1]+  Stopped                    tracepath -4 104.26.12.50

CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin # wget https://104.26.12.50/
Connecting to 104.26.12.50 (104.26.12.50:443)
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin # tracepath -4 104.26.12.50
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1492
 1:  192.168.1.179                                       375.207ms !H
 1:  192.168.1.179                                       2750.098ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1492 

CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin # ip route flush cache

CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin # tracepath -4 104.26.12.50
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           0.994ms 
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           0.776ms 
 2:  192.168.1.1                                           0.809ms pmtu 1492
 2:  10.11.128.1                                           5.180ms 
 3:  211.136.62.237                                       13.072ms 
 4:  111.24.14.45                                          4.863ms 
^Z[2]+  Stopped                    tracepath -4 104.26.12.50
CoreELEC:~/.opt/bin #
```

Comment: Can you show us results of **traceroute 104.26.12.50** before and after wget?

Comment: thank a lot. the traceroute result has be appended.

Comment: Second hop (10.11.128.1) seems to filter you out. Are you at home or in enterprise network? (Look to me the later, have/can you ask your IT ?)

Comment: Don't use traceroute when trying this, use tcptraceroute with an initial hop.

Comment: You should provide your full network configuration: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule` (and if there's any vpn or more then 3 entries in ip rule, the relevant additional information). Also what kernel version is it?

Comment: yes. the 10.11.128.1 is ths internal network.

Comment: I'm confused about why 'wget' make my network broen. and the problem not occur at another macbook in same network

Comment: Also as Bib wrote, using wget and tcp (or tcptraceroute or traceroute with a tcp option like -T) might trigger something that tcpdump and udp doesn't. So if 192.168.1.1 is doing a redirect in some cases it's not obvious: your ip route get appears to lack the 2nd line in its output (the one that would include a cache redirect entry). You'd probably need to know all your network layout and describe it too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the https problem. The encryption on that port is broken or else it's using virtual hosts, in which case, you need to connect with the host name rather than IP address.

```
localhost:~ $ openssl s_client -connect 104.26.12.50:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139928269652608:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Comment: Thank you. i known  i need to connect with the host name. use ip addr just for show the odd case directly.  I'm confused about why 'wget' make my network broen. and the problem not occur at another macbook in same network

Comment: It isn't. Something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by downgrade the firmware version of my wireless router（netgear R6400v2）
from v1.0.4.106_10.0.80 to v1.0.2.62_10.0.46